# Average distance between consecutive digits of normal number

Tags: number-theory, random-variables, expectation, variance

Let $x\in [0,1)$ be a real number. Let $x=0.a_1a_2a_3\ldots$ be the expansion of $x$ in base $b.$

Consider the average distance between two consecutive digits of $x:$

$$d(x):=lim_{N\to +\infty}\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{N}|a_{i+1}-a_i|}{N} $$

**First question:** Does anybody study this quantity so far?

More precisley, it is quite easy to construct a real number $x$ for which the above limit does not exist. It just suffices to choose the digits so that the quantity $$X_n:=\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{N}|a_{i+1}-a_i|}{N}$$
oscillates as $N$ increases.

**Second question:** If we choose a normal number $x$ 
then does the above limit exist?

Surely if $x$ is normal it is possible to evaluate the expectation 
$$\mathbb E(X_n).$$
In fact a simple calculation shows that this is equal to $$\frac{b^2-1}{3b}$$ 
(to this aim remember that the expectation is linear and consider the possible values assumed by $|a_{i+1}-a_i|$.)

**Third question:** The variance of $X_n$ seems more difficult. Do you have any idea to find it?

Comment: I'd start by looking through Kuipers/Niederreiter's [**Uniform Distribution of Sequences**](http://web.maths.unsw.edu.au/~josefdick/preprints/KuipersNied_book.pdf). Possibly the notion of "strong normality" in Adrian Belshaw's 2005 Master of Science thesis [**On the Normality of Numbers**](http://people.math.sfu.ca/~numthry/report/2006jan13.pdf) is relevant. **(continued)**

Comment: Incidentally, a question was asked about Belshaw's thesis in Mathematics Stack Exchange --- [What is the intuition behind the definition of a simply strongly normal number?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2761572/what-is-the-intuition-behind-the-definition-of-a-simply-strongly-normal-number) --- that has not generated any answers or comments.

Answer (score 1):

First we exclude the case of equality, and the case of decreasing (focus only on increasing, as the probability of decreasing by a value is equal to the probability of increasing by it overall) I'll add the case of equality at the end.

Case: $\Delta=9$

Occurrences: $0\to 9 (1)$

Case: $\Delta=8$

Occurrences: $0\to 8, 1\to 9\space(2)$

Case: $\Delta=7$

Occurrences: $0\to 7, 1\to 8, 2\to 9\space(3)$

Case: $\Delta=6$

Occurrences: $0\to 6, 1\to 7, 2\to 8, 3\to9\space(4)$

etc

Case: $\Delta=1$

Occurrences: 9

There are $10$ cases of equality, so the total cases are $$2(1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8)+10=82$$

We have $\frac{2}{82}=\frac{1}{41}$ chance of the difference being $9$

$\frac{4}{82}=\frac{2}{41}$ chance of it being $8$.

and so forth.

Overall we get:

$$\frac{2}{82}\times9+\frac{4}{82}\times8+\frac{6}{82}\times7+\frac{8}{82}\times6+\frac{10}{82}\times5+\frac{12}{82}\times4+\frac{14}{82}\times3+\frac{16}{82}\times2+\frac{18}{82}\times1+\frac{20}{82}\times0$$
$$=\frac{330}{82}\approx4.02$$

Comment: This is the same calculation that i do for the expectation (except that your denominators should be 100 instead of 82: you miss a 9 in the sum). But what about the variance?

Comment: Oh yes of colurse. I made a mistake and realised it after that point... then forgot to amend it